# Iteration over list with shifting starting point

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration

Using Python3, I need to iterate over the list of elements sequentially starting from an arbitrary i (i <= 6), complete the full iteration cycle, repeat it starting with i += 1 and so on.  This cycle should not end. In content, this is the getting of the names of the days of the week, starting with the current one. For example, if today is Wednesday, as a result of iterations I have to get a list [Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday]. It seems to be quite simple, but I am at a dead end. I will be grateful for the hint or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to get an infinite iterable that produces the sequence you want:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

for x in chain(the_list[i:], cycle(the_list)):
    print(x)
```

Used as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, cycle
>>> the_list = range(10)
>>> i = 6
>>> for x in chain(the_list[i:], cycle(the_list)):
...     print(x)
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
[... forever ...]
```

---

Equivalently use `cycle`+[`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> for x in islice(cycle(the_list), i, None):
...     print(x)
>>> for x in islice(cycle(the_list), i, 20):
...     print(x)
... 
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
[... forever ...]
```

Comment: What's `i` here?

Comment: @jpp The Op introduced the name `i` to refer to the starting index

Comment: OK, understood, always useful to include it if OP's code isn't complete or just pseudo-logic.

Comment: Seems like a list till the previous day is required.

Comment: `starting from an arbitrary i (i <= 6), complete the full iteration cycle, repeat it starting with i += 1` Where's the repeating starting with `i+1` part? Or have I misread the question?

Comment: @jpp I interpreted that as the OP meaning repeating starting with `i = 1` and the OP incorrectly thinking that `1` is the first index in the list, since the statement as is does not make sense. If the OP actually intended something different they can comment and clarify that.

Comment: You could save the chain and just do `for x in cycle(lst[i:]+lst[:i]):`

Comment: Thank you all so much, I didn't think about it before)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually put the modulo operator `%` to good use in such cycling scenarios:

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

i = 2  # Wednesday

while True:
    print(days[i])
    i += 1
    i = i % len(days)  # 7 => 0

Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import chain, dropwhile, repeat


def endless_daynames(starting_day):
    daynames = [
        'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
        'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    # get starting day name 
    starting_day_name = daynames[starting_day] 
    # creating an endless iterable from an origin list
    endless_list = chain.from_iterable(repeat(daynames))
    # drop first items before we meet a required one
    shifted_list = dropwhile(lambda x: x != starting_day_name, endless_list)
    # yield values from it
    yield from shifted_list
```

Comment: alternatively you can use cycle(): `endless_list = cycle(daynames)`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,you are trying to get week days in any given days
You can pass week days name and get a list in same rotated order.
Please have a look of this:-

```
from collections import deque
def rotate_week(week_days):
    a = deque(["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"])
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(a)):
        d[a[i]] = i
    number_to_rotate = d.get(week_days)
    a.rotate(-number_to_rotate)
    print(list(a))
rotate_week('Wednesday')
```

**Output as :-**

```
['Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```

Comment: A result should be endless